# is_reverse "second" error in Think Python

Tags: python

There is an is_reverse program in Think Python as follows:

```
def is_reverse(word1, word2):
    if len(word1) != len(word2):
        return False

    i = 0
    j = len(word2) - 1

    while j > 0:
        print(i, j)
        if word1[i] != word2[j]:
            return False
        i = i + 1
        j = j - 1
    return True
```

The author asks to figure out an error in it which I am unable to after much brainstorming.

The program works just fine and returns this:

```
0  3
1  2
2  1
True
```

The error pertains to this output. Please help me figure it out.

Comment: probably the print function, because the is_reverse function should only return a Boolean, not print on the screen.

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Program as you said works just fine!

Comment: The print function is there for error checking in the first place. This is not the error. Yes, the program works fine but there is an error pertaining to iteration which I'm unable to figure out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function suppose to check if word1 is reserve of word2 (I think, please post what you expect the function to do next time)

The function does not check final word and beginning word. It does not check word1[-1] (last character) and word2[0] (first character)

```
w1 = 'Dogx'
w2 = 'ggoD'
print (is_reverse(w1, w2))
```

The problem is here:

```
while j > 0:
```

The loop terminate before checking word2[0]. I suggest add `=`. THus, change the condition to:

```
while j >= 0:
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the while condition in is_reverse method to -

```
while j >= 0:
```

Comment: Amol, you rock, brother!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the indentation is incorrect? Would not error if it was this:

```
def is_reverse(word1, word2):
    if len(word1) != len(word2):
        return False

    i = 0
    j = len(word2) - 1

    while j > 0:
        print(i, j)
        if word1[i] != word2[j]:
            return False
        i = i + 1
        j = j - 1
    return True
```

I would write this function like this:

```
def is_reverse(word1, word2):
    return word1[::-1] == word2
```

But neither of these functions deal with uppercase to lowercase comparisons. I'm not sure how you want to handle that.

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_reverse(word3, word4):
if len(word3) != len(word4):
    return False
iii = 0
j = len(word4)-1
while j >= 0:
    print(iii, j)
    print(word3[iii], word4[j])
    print("----------------")
    if word3[iii] != word4[j]:
        return False
    iii += 1
    print("j printed", j)
    j -= 1
```

is_reverse("spot","tops")